# sudo apt-get update not working in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: apt

I want to install some softwares in my ubuntu 19.04 but when i type any command related to apt i get a very big error.

I typed the command `sudo apt-get update` and got this huge error:

[image]

Comment: This release is old and there is no longer support for it, sorry.

Comment: what happens if you try to browse to `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` ?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Standard releases have a supported life of 9 months, a LTS or *long-term-support* release has a supported life of 5 years (extended via use of ESM longer but off-topic on this site, but note flavors only offer 3 years for LTS).  Your 2019-April release (19.04 using the *yy.mm* format of Ubuntu releases) is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus software repository have moved to old-releases. You should have *release-upgraded* when prompted before it reached EOL (see EOLUpgrades in prior comment)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your description says *disco* (19.04) but your paste says *eoan* (19.10), however the result is the same, both are now EOL & thus repositories have been *moved* (or deleted for many 3rd party, both official & unofficial due EOL).